# Ubuntu 18.04 RJDBC:JDBC connection to oracle hangs no response

Tags: r, ubuntu, jdbc, dbconnection, rjdbc

I developed a shiny application using data from an oracle database, my app is developed and running smoothly in my windows environment. To deploy my app within my colleges I wrote it as a package and installed this packages on a ubuntu server.
   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
Shiny server is installed and finding the package, app is running.

But when I try to create a connection to oracle, my app disconnects and ask me to reload the session.

So I extracted just the code to build the connection and included several messages and it hangs while using dbconnet from RJDBC package.

I checked several environment variables like PATH, JAVA_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I have next to no experience with linux.

**My R Version**
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

**Java Version**
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

**Oracle Database**
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I am using the driver ojdbc7.jar since it seems to be the latest version.

```
    library(rJava)
    library(DBI)
    library(RJDBC)

    options(java.parameters="-Xmx2g")
    .jinit()
    print(.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.version"))

    initialize_db_con <- function(driverClass = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
                          classPath = "pathtomyfile/ojdbc7.jar",
                          dbn = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/mydb',
                          usr = NULL, pwd = NULL) {
      driverClass <- 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
      message("Setting user and password manually")

      creds <- list(user = usr, pw = pwd)


      drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = driverClass, classPath = classPath, identifier.quote = '´')
      message("driver is set")
      con <- RJDBC::dbConnect(drv = drv, dbn, creds$user, creds$pw)
      message("connection has been build")
      return(con)
    }


    usr <- "myuser"
    pwd <- "mypassword"

    con <- initialize_db_con(usr=usr, pwd = pwd)
```

So after waiting for about 30 seconds this error message appears.

```
    Error in .jcall("java/sql/DriverManager", "Ljava/sql/Connection;",      "getConnection",  :
    ignoring SIGPIPE signal
```

Why can the connection not be build, any suggestions?

Comment: this list is growing and growing, no clue what it means...?!

Comment: Oh, press `CTRL + C`

Comment: ok, so I get this 6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5102ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.021/0.023/0.005 ms

Comment: I did a bit of searching and could only find this post about your error from 2012: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Intermittent-connectivity-issues-for-JDBC-Oracle-td4644960.html When I looked at the archive (Q4 2012) the answer seemed to be, "try ROracle". Sorry I can't be more help

Comment: Thank you Phil, I found this Page too. But I am pretty certain there must solution with rJava, RJDBC. I also found this page https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/784, could this be related to my problem? And if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: It could be worth downgrading to java 10 or upgrading to java 11.27 to see?

Comment: But Java 10 is not supported for ubuntu 18.04 or am I mixing things up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194835/discussion-between-phil-and-alina-ludewig).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, and the user who asked it moved on long ago, but just in case anybody lands here with the same problem I will post my solution: I solved it by  adding this line:

```
options(java.parameters="-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom")
library(rJava)
```

Apparently [there is a problem](https://www.usn-it.de/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/) with the JDBC driver on Linux due the blocking nature of /dev/random. A tcpdump trace showed traffic but the connection got stuck after an "auth session" TNS packet. An strace showed that the process was locked waiting for /dev/random:

```
open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY)           = 22
...
read(22, 0x7ffc27416f10, 8)             = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

A bit of googling made the rest.

I have been stuck on this some days, and that's the answer I would have liked to be posted here, so there it is.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with a similar problem, I want to post my solution.
The Environment variables had been set only for the User root, but not for all other users including the user from shiny-app.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile

Also very helpful to understand the process of connecting ubuntu to oracle was this page 
https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/sqlnet_overview/